# Fazer Distinct Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou tentando realizar o `Distinct`, em meu model de `Phones`, mas nenhuma das opções que estou tentando dar certo. Poderiam me indicar oque estou fazendo errado ?

Abaixo descrevi várias formas que já tentei fazer, mas nenhuma delas funcionaram para mim, poderiam me dar uma luz ?

```
model.Phones = model.Phones.Where(x => x != null && x.Phone != null).ToList();
1ª - model.Phones = (from p in model.Phones select p).Distinct().ToList();
2ª - model.Phones = model.Phones.Select(a => a).Distinct().ToList();
```

Tentei das duas formas acima, mais nada funciona.

Exemplo de como recebo os dados abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
model.Phones = model.Phones.Select(x => x.Phone).Distinct().ToList();
```

Recebo seguinte erro:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<KonBase.Areas.Admin.Models.ApplicationCondominiumViewModels.PhoneViewModel>'`

E:

```
model.Phones = model.Phones.GroupBy(x => x.Phone).ToList();
```

Recebo seguinte erro:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, KonBase.Areas.Admin.Models.ApplicationCondominiumViewModels.PhoneViewModel>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<KonBase.Areas.Admin.Models.ApplicationCondominiumViewModels.PhoneViewModel>'`

Comment: Seu model phone só tem o atributo string? Se tiver mais de um e eles tiverem diferentes não adianta só dar distinct

Comment: Sim, eles possuem só string

Answer (score 1):

Acabei de descobrir, na verdade por estar comparando os objetos o distinct não avalia eles como sendo iguais. Algumas alternativas são:
Group by:

```
List<Phones> teste = Phones.GroupBy(x=>x.Phone).ToList();
```

Select no campo(vai retornar uma lista de strings) antes do distinct

```
List<String> teste = Phones.Select(a => a.nome).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Amigo nenhuma das duas opções serviram para mim recebo os seguintes erros: Na primeira opção `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, KonBase.Areas.Admin.Models.ApplicationCondominiumViewModels.PhoneViewModel>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<KonBase.Areas.Admin.Models.ApplicationCondominiumViewModels.PhoneViewModel>'
`

Comment: E na segunda opção : `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<KonBase.Areas.Admin.Models.ApplicationCondominiumViewModels.PhoneViewModel>'
`